# CSRF exempt for contactform - Django

Tags: django, cookies, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf

Is it safe to use a CSRF exempt for a contactform or a form using the send_mail function from Django?

So according to the docs;

> The first defense against CSRF attacks is to ensure that GET requests
> (and other ‘safe’ methods, as defined by RFC 7231#section-4.2.1) are
> side effect free.

Is a POST request, which only creates an email message and does not touch the database, considered as a "safe" method?

Example code

```
from django.core.mail import BadHeaderError, send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def send_email(request):
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
    message = request.POST.get('message', '')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '')
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        # In reality we'd use a form class
        # to get proper validation errors.
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

*example from docs

I'm just wondering if I'm not missing something before I add the CSRF exempt. Now I hear you thinking, why would someone want to disable the CSRF validation?

In the EU we have to comply to the GDPR. By setting a cookie, we need to explicitly ask the user to accept cookies, if we can prevent setting cookies, we do not need to show the cookie prompt ;)

Comment: Honestly I think you are misinterpreting the GDPR:  according to the mindset of the GDPR it is much more critical to store personal data (in this case the email address of the sender) in your database than to use cookies. So in my opinion you will have to ask for a permission anyway.

Comment: Do we save the users email-address?

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the csrf_excempt decorator you are saying that anyone from anywhere can do a post to you view, you are disabling the validation that django provides when anyone in your site loads the contact form in their browser, Maybe they cannot do anything with the database but they are be able to send spam to your admin@example.com account from anywhere without even load your form view.